# i cant append the form to a list

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, append

why wont this code append the **task** to **tasks**
i'v been taking CS50 course, and after i apply this code i didn't see the expected result
i tried everything but still the **form** wont append to the list of **tasks**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="Task Text")
    
tasks = ['finish', 'study', 'reset']


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    
    return render(request, "task/index.html",{
        "tasks":tasks
    })
    
def add(request):
    if request.method =="post":
        form = NewTaskForm(request.post)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]
            tasks.append(task)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("task:index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "task/add.html", {
                "form":form
            })
    return render(request, "task/add.html",{
        "form":NewTaskForm()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems, the method is always in uppercase, and the data is stored in `request.POST`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]
            tasks.append(task)
            return redirect('task:index')
    else:
        form = NewTaskForm()
    return render(request, 'task/add.html', {'form': form})
```

That being said, storing the data in a (global) variable is a very bad idea. It introduces global state, which is a severe antipattern.